# Scilab issue with exec command

Tags: scilab

I am using Scinote 5.4.0 with OSX 10.7.4. I am unable to execute script files from the console using the `exec("path")` command; when I do so, only the first line of the script file is read.

Example:

```
-->exec("plot1.sce") 
-->x=[0:.1:10]'; //(the first line of my code)
```

If however I "execute with echo" from the editor Scinote, the script will run just fine.

Does anybody know what is going on? (The script files I am trying to run are in my present working directory).

Thanks!

Update: I just installed Scilab on an identical machine and the same thing is happening.

Update: Per Scilab's bugtracker, it appears to be caused by Scinote defaulting to cr eol on a mac. I don't really know what this means or how to fix it, but the adventure continues!

Update: I found the solution!:http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.mathematics.scilab.user/6184

In the preferences, I changed the eol to Unix, and the default file encoding to iso-8859-1. I restarted and exec is now working!

Comment: just spent half an hour searching for the problem before figuring it out myself. thanks for pointing it out here

Comment: Please post an answer so that the question   does not remain without one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The link is not easy to follow so here's the answer (pasted)

> The problem is actually scinote's, not scilab's. I don't have a Lion
>   machine to check if I'm correct, but it seems scinote's file encoding
>   is no longer compatible in ML. I discovered that when I opened scinote
>   generated files with a different text editor (vi) the new lines
>   weren't encoded right for my machine. The other give-away was that
>   executing scripts written prior to upgrading worked fine.
>
> Go to preferences and in the scinotes tab, switch default file
>   encoding to iso-8859-1. I also switched the end-of-line to Unix.